# ¿Cómo volver definitivamente a un commit anterior en Git?

Tags: git, git-commit

Estoy intentando volver atrás en el tiempo con Git pero creo que no llego a entender bien de que manera se realiza. Explico mi procedimiento.

1. Creo un repositorio de prueba iniciándolo con la licencia
2. Creo el readme y confirmo con un commit
3. Añado un fichero llamado "index.html" de prueba, realizo commit y push
   (Hasta aquí todo bien)
4. Hago git log para ver el hash del commit inicial (donde solo tenía la licencia)
5. Hago git reset --hard HASHdelCOMMIT
   (En local se borran los ficheros)

Ahora es donde me pierdo. ¿Cómo puedo subir estos cambios a GitHub? Es decir, que se borren todos los ficheros y se quede el repositorio solo con el fichero de la licencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer un push en el estado actual sólo tienes que forzarlo hacia el origen (-f o --force).

```
git push origin <nombre_de_tu_rama> --force
```